# 'while' loop in Python

Tags: python

I'm starting to learn Python by throwing myself in the deep end and trying a bunch of exercises.

In this particular exercise, I'm trying to make a program to ask the name and age of the user and tell the user the year they're going to turn 100.

I tried putting in a yes/no input to ask if the user's birthday has passed this year, and give the correct year they will turn 100, based on that.

I wanted to incorporate a while loop so that if the user enters an answer that isn't "yes" or "no", I ask them to answer either "yes" or "no". I also wanted to make the answer case insensitive.

```
print("What is your name?")
userName = input("Enter name: ")

print("Hello, " + userName + ", how old are you?")
userAge = input("Enter age: ")

print("Did you celebrate your birthday this year?")

while answer.lower() not in ('yes', 'no'):
    answer = input ("Yes/No: ")


if answer.lower() == 'yes':
          print ("You are " + userAge + " years old! That means you'll be turning 100 years old in the year " + str(2019 - int(userAge) + 100))


elif answer.lower() == 'no':
          print ("You'll be turning " + str(int(userAge) + 1) + " this year! That means you'll be turning 100 years old in the year " + str(2019 - int(userAge) + 99))

else:
        print ('Please type "Yes" or "No"')


print ("Have a good life")
```

Comment: You're calling `answer.lower()` when `answer` is not declared, put a `answer = ''` before the while loop and see if it works

Answer (score 3):

You should addd the input before trying to access the answer.lower method, so it will be something like:

```
answer = input('Yes/No: ')
while answer.lower() not in ('yes','no'):
   answer = input('Yes/No: ')
```

Check geckos response in the comments: just initialize answer with an empty string